# Objective C unsigned char to negative int

Tags: objective-c, int, unsigned-char

I've to transform

`unsigned char x = 0xEC` in `int y = -20`

`unsigned char x = 0xF0` in `int y = -16`

if I cast like this (assuming `x = 0xF0`)

```
int y = (int)x
```

I obtain `x = 240` that is the correct decimal representation of `0xF0`. Where I'am wrong ? How can I get a negative number ?

Comment: Did you try assigning the `unsigned char` to a `char`? And then the `char` to an `int`?

Comment: @rmaddy is right.  You want the high bit set in a signed 8-bit data type and then sign extension works when you move to a larger data type.

Comment: @rmaddy it works perfectly ! Put your comment in an answer so I can accept as correct. Thanks.

Comment: (int)(char)x or simply (char)x is also ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the `unsigned char` to a signed `char` first, then going to an `int` will give you the result you want:

```
unsigned char x = 0xEC;
char x1 = (char)x;
int x2 = x1;
```

As CRD points out, the C specification leaves the fact that `char` could either be signed or unsigned, so the safest solution here is to be explicit.

```
signed char x1 = (signed char)x;
```

Comment: I think you meant `signed char`?

Comment: @CRD `char` is the same as `signed char`.

Comment: no it isn't, that's the point. In C whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation dependant, hence the need to use `signed char` to be correct without assumptions.

Comment: @CRD I stand corrected. I updated the answer to reflect this detail. Thanks.